# Create directory and upload image in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
 $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
 $directory = Storage::makeDirectory($this->objProperty->id); //create directory using property id.
 Storage::disk('local')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
```

Currently this code upload image into **storage/upload/** directory but i want to upload this image into newly created directory(`$directory`).
Example: **storage/upload/1/test.jpg**

Comment: This needs some more context, but I suppose that `disk('local')` is a Flysystem "disk" which is configured to point to **storage/upload/** Is that correct?

Comment: yes, in filesystem i have assign driver local to upload and its create upload directory and  $directory = Storage::makeDirectory($this->objProperty->id); //create directory using property id.
 code also create directory as per id, but i can move image to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify folder in `put()` method:

```php
Storage::disk('local')->put(
    $this->objProperty->id.'/'.$file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,
    File::get($file)
);
```